# jquery .stop() not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to build a menu where only the first item is shown by default, and when you hover over it the rest of the items slide out, and are hidden again when the mouse leaves.  It's mostly working but if the mouse exits before it's finished sliding out then the hide function isn't called.  I thought `stop()` was supposed to take care of this but it doesn't seem to have any affect.

```
$(function(){
    $("#menubar").children(".breadcrumbs").children("li + li").hide();

    $("#menubar .breadcrumbs").hover(function() {
        $(this).children("li + li").stop().show("slide", {}, 'slow');
    }, function() {
        $(this).children("li + li").stop().hide("slide", {}, 'slow');
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bemace/CYBTc/3/)

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not the biggest animation genius, but I bet it has to do with the fact that you're rebuilding the jQuery object in each handler. Try this:

```
$(function(){
    var children = $('#menubar .breadcrumbs').children('li + li');
    children.hide();

    $("#menubar .breadcrumbs").hover(function() {
        children.stop().show("slide", {}, 'slow');
    }, function() {
        children.stop().hide("slide", {}, 'slow');
    });
});
```

*edit* — @melee points out in comments that the behavior of this particular setup is not always stable. If you carefully hold the mouse over towards the right edge of the "Home" `<li>` (near the ">" character), then sometimes the animation sort-of freaks out. It's not clear why, but the browser just gets very confused about where the elements should be rendered.

Comment: Not sure if this is specific to jsFiddle or Firefox, but when you hold the mouse over the `Home >` carrot, it goes all sorts of crazy.

Comment: Happened on Chrome too but I can't reproduce it. I think it's a problem with the slide ani - also I tested it in FF4 :)

Comment: I think it happens because at that particular point, when the li's are sliding in, your mouse is going over those elements so it's retriggering the slide event when they pass through, causing a loop. I *think* you'd need to incorporate some callbacks and variables to get it working perfectly.

Comment: I had a similar issue and this worked for me. I wonder why, though; normally there should be no problem doing `$("#stuff").hide(200); $("#stuff").stop();`, but apparently jQuery forgets about the set if you use the `children()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are parameters to the STOP(), function, (true,true), (false,false) have you tried altering these to change the desired effect?

Comment: I've tried different combinations but none seem to make any difference.

Answer (score -1):

The definition of the stop function is

```
.stop( [ clearQueue ], [ jumpToEnd ] )
```

The oficial site goes...

> clearQueue: A Boolean indicating whether
>   to remove queued animation as well.
>   Defaults to false.
>
> jumpToEnd: A Boolean indicating whether
>   to complete the current animation
>   immediately. Defaults to false.

This is from http://api.jquery.com/stop/