# reset state to original on hover out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have something like:

```
 $(".leftCues").hover(
        function(){
                $(".item1", ".item2", ".item3", ".item4", ".item5").stop(true,true)
                $(".item1").animate({opacity:1.0}, 2000, function()  {
                  $(".item1").animate({opacity:0.0},2000, function() {
                    $(".item2").animate({opacity:1.0},2000, function()  {
                      $(".item2").animate({opacity:0.0}, 2000, function() {
                        $(".item3").animate({opacity:1.0}, 2000, function()  {
                          $(".item3").animate({opacity:0.0}, 2000, function() {
                            $(".item4").animate({opacity:1.0},2000, function()  {
                              $(".item4").animate({opacity:0.0}, 2000, function() {
                                $(".item5").animate({opacity:1.0}, 2000, function()  {
                                });
                              });
                            });
                          });
                        });
                      });
                    });
                  });
                });
        },
        function(){
                $(".item5").css('opacity', 0.0);
        }       
  );
```

CSS:

```
.item5, .item3, .item1 {
  clear: both;
  float:left;
  margin-top: 6%;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  opacity:0.0;
}

.item2, .item4 {
  clear: both;
  float:right;
  margin-top: 6%;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  opacity:0.0;
}
```

My animation works fine when I hover on but when I hover out, my previous state is not getting reset. Now when hover on again, a new animation starts while the previous animation is still running.

How can I reset the my previous hover on state? On hover out, I want to go back to original state (like before my very first hover on)

In my animation, I just toggle opacity from 1.0 to 0.0 and my css starts with opacity 0.0.

Please help.

Comment: please post your complete hover function

Answer (score 3):

You could use `.fadeIn()` or `fadeOut()` if there is nothing other to animate.

Something like this

```
$('#item').hover( function() {
      $('#item2, #item3, #item4, #item5').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
  },
  function () {
    $('#item2, #item3, #item4, #item5').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
  }
);
```

The `.stop(true, true)` is important because it makes it jump at the end of the animation. [Here's the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).

Comment: fadeIn fadeOut uses display:none which shifts my divs up and down...I tried fade* but then had to resort to opacity toggling. Would stop() work with animate

Comment: Well now that the OP posted his whole code, this answer is no longer what he's looking for... but I'll keep it in case it helps someone else!

Comment: just to confirm, you answer is not my soln right?? I tried as in my edited code.

Comment: No it's not the solution. You updated the code and now you show that you animate item 1... fade in, fade out. The animate item 2... fade in, fade out... So you want to wait for each item to "blink" and the pass to the next one. Is that what you want?

Comment: you stop suggestion works...I upvoted but could not accept fully as an answer...This solved my problem...after your suggestion I was dealing with this problem....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406903/jquery-stop-not-working...thank you much

Answer (score 1):

You may use jQuery's `.mouseover()` and `.mouseout()` functions.

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

```
$(".leftCues").mouseover(function(){
                $(".item1").animate({opacity:1.0}, 2000, function()  {
                  $(".item1").animate({opacity:0.0},2000, function() {
                    $(".item2").animate({opacity:1.0},2000, function()  {
                      $(".item2").animate({opacity:0.0}, 2000, function() {
                        $(".item3").animate({opacity:1.0}, 2000, function()  {
                          $(".item3").animate({opacity:0.0}, 2000, function() {
                            $(".item4").animate({opacity:1.0},2000, function()  {
                              $(".item4").animate({opacity:0.0}, 2000, function() {
                                $(".item5").animate({opacity:1.0}, 2000, function()  {
                                });
                              });
                            });
                          });
                        });
                      });
                    });
                  });
                });
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(".item5").css('opacity', 0.0);
});
```

Comment: it will not solve the problem right? Problem is what should I do at mouse leave time so that I can reset what started at mouse over time...issue is its not getting reset at mouse leave....pardon my ignorance

Comment: can you provide their default (normal) styling?

Comment: make a demo at jsfiddle.net